# Multiple Buttons to insert text into input

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to have a button with a search value for our most common searches.  What I was trying to do is user clicks button and inserts the text WITH the quotes "Some Text".

Right now this is what I am using for a single button.  How would I make this so I can use one script with multiple buttons?

```
  <button onclick="searchText()" data-product-name="iPhone 12 Pro">iPhone 12 Pro Max</button> <----Current Button

<button onclick="searchText()" data-product-name="Pixel 5">Pixel</button> <---- Added for what Id like
<button onclick="searchText()" data-product-name="LG">LG</button><---- Added for what Id like
<button onclick="searchText()" data-product-name="Samsung S20 Plus">Samsung S20 Plus</button><---- Added for what Id like

  <script>
  var i = 0;
  var txt = '"iPhone 12 Pro Max"';
  var speed = 50;

  function searchText() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      document.getElementById("search-query").value += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  }
  </script>
```

I tried adding the following but did not work.

```
var txt = element.getAttribute('data-product-name');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = '"iPhone 12 Pro Max"';
var speed = 50;
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('button')
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var txt = this.getAttribute('data-product-name');
    console.log(txt);
  });
}
```

```html
<button data-product-name="iPhone 12 Pro">iPhone 12 Pro Max</button>
<button data-product-name="Pixel 5">Pixel</button>
<button data-product-name="LG">LG</button>
<button data-product-name="Samsung S20 Plus">Samsung S20 Plus</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id of the button to the searchText.
and read the text using jquery or plain js

```
   <!--html --->
   <button onclick="searchText('buttonOne')" id= "buttonOne" data-product-name="Samsung S20 Plus">Samsung S20 Plus</button><---- Added for what Id like

   // javascript
   function(buttonId){
        var text = document.getElementById(buttonId).innerHTML
        // process the text with your business logic here
   }
```